# SSL Certificate getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError) Rails-4.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl-certificate

I have Rails 4.2.0 application with ruby version 2.2.0. I have a requirement where I need to create an SSL certificate for the test environment.

To set-up an SSL certificate I followed the below steps:

**step-1:** `brew install mkcert`

**step-2:** Added entry on `/etc/hosts` for the localhost domain i.e `127.0.0.1  localhost.application_name`

**step-3:** Created the key and certificate files for domain which I created by `mkcert localhost.application_name`

**step-4:**  Then move those certificate files into the `config\ssl` folder

**step-5:** And then I start my rails server like `bundle exec rails server -p 3000 -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=config/ssl/localhost.application_name-key.pem&cert=config/ssl/localhost.application_name.pem'`

When I run the rails s with the below command I am facing an error `'getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)`

For more clarity, I am attaching the screenshot after rails s execute.

[image]

I already tried a lot of solution which is being already present in StackOverflow but no luck as of now. Any help will be appreciated!

**Note:** I have rails application setup with Docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding syntax you provided (with `ssl://` scheme) is used with `puma` application server.

`WEBrick`, which was the default application server with Rails 4.x, doesn't support this binding scheme.

So you can jump to `puma` by simply adding to `Gemfile`

```
gem 'puma'
```

and then run

```
bundle install
```

Then you'll be able to start your app as you're used to.